# Android: make Recyclerview behave like LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-recyclerview

I have a layout such:

```
<LinearLayout>
   <TextView/>
   <LinearLayout> <-- needs to be a dynamic list
      <JohnDoeView/>
      <JohnDoeView/>
   </LinearLayout>
   <TextView/>
   <LinearLayout> <-- needs to be a another dynamic list
      <JohnDoeView/>
      <JohnDoeView/>
      <JohnDoeView/>
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

this results in the image below, and i can scroll the **WHOLE** layout together.

But when i try to replace those `LinearLayout`'s with `RecyclerView`'s I get **TWO** separate scroll areas , like two fixed boxes that scroll **independently**.

```
<LinearLayout>
   <TextView/>
   <RecyclerView/>
   <TextView/>
   <RecyclerView/>
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I get the same effect as `LinearLayout` but with having **Dynamic** content ??

[image: How I want the layout to look]

Comment: Did you try using addView() and removeView() method of LinearLayout? Using these two methods you can dynamically add and remove views from LinearLayout. The only drawback is here over RecyclerView and ListView is that you have to manage adding and removing views manually which can be tedious and can also produce code smell.

Comment: There is a reason we use `RecyclerView`'s , I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Then just don't try to adjust the wheel and adopt the default behaviour. :)

Comment: but doesn't it look much nicer like that ? :)

Comment: Just have a recyclerview with more than one layout?. You can have a view for the "My block list" then have a view for the names and just add them dynamically.

Comment: @Varundroid programming without trying to "adjust the wheel" would be quite boring!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two solutions.

1. Insert the whole layout inside a `ScrollView`.
2. Use a single `RecyclerView`.

**Solution 1**

For this you need to make the `RecyclerView` wrap its content. Sadly, you can't just put `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` because `RecyclerView` does not support that. Luckily there are custom solutions for that. I've been using it and it works well.

For instance, there's [this](https://github.com/serso/android-linear-layout-manager) custom `LinearLayoutManager` which you could assign to both the `RecyclerView`s. Just follow the instructions in the page I linked.

**Solution 2**

You could use a single `RecyclerView`. This might require harder work because you have to:

- merge your adapter into a single one;
- assign to a certain position your divider (`TextView`, `Switch` or whatever).

This is surely possible, just take a look at one of the (many) examples out there on `RecyclerView` with multiple child types.

Comment: Solution one is good , and it works , but now it's not scrolling as smoothly; it stops scrolling as soon as my finger leaves.

Comment: never mind fixed it with `recycler_view.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`

Comment: one more thing , when I delete an item , it leaves a blank space , in other words , the size of the `RecyclerView` is not updating correctly. any solution ?

Comment: Are you using animations?

Comment: using default animations, is there a way to set `endAnimation` listener ?

Comment: The LinearLayoutManager I linked to, can work with animations only if the child have equal height and you set `linearManager.setChildSize(int childSize)`. See [here](https://github.com/serso/android-linear-layout-manager/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/org/solovyev/android/views/llm/LinearLayoutManager.java) and read the class description.

Comment: how do i get the child size ?

Answer (score 0):

`LinearLayout` can handle dynamic changes. It can even animate them, if you use the `android:animateLayoutChanges` attribute. `ListView` or `Recycler` are interesting when the number of items is large (i.e. much more than what the screen can display), to avoid to have a lot of invisible views.

If you really want to use a `RecyclerView` you could use only one, with multiple [view types](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29), e.g. one for `TextView`, one for the `JohnDoeView`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this layout structure,

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to nest `RecyclerView`s or `ListView`s or any other scrolling views. You need only the external view to be `RecyclerView`. The inner lists can be managed via very simple `ListLayout` class with an adapter for each sub-list.

```
public class ListLayout extends LinearLayout {
    private Adapter mAdapter;
    private Observer mObserver = new Observer();

    public ListLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ListLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ListLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public Adapter getAdapter()
    {
        return mAdapter;
    }

    public void setAdapter(Adapter adapter) {
        if (mAdapter != null)
            mAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(mObserver);

        mAdapter = adapter;
        adapter.registerDataSetObserver(mObserver);
        mObserver.onChanged();
    }

    private class Observer extends DataSetObserver {

        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            final List<View> oldViews = new ArrayList<View>(getChildCount());

            for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++)
                oldViews.add(getChildAt(i));

            final Iterator<View> iter = oldViews.iterator();

            removeAllViews();

            for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                View convertView = iter.hasNext() ? iter.next() : null;
                View newView = mAdapter.getView(i, convertView, ListLayout.this);
                addView(newView);
            }
            super.onChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onInvalidated() {
            removeAllViews();
            super.onInvalidated();
        }
    }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/sevar83/0e27c26142f2fba97d57